# Gulp find my Bower components and concat them

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

I have a stupid question, I guess: **I'm trying to make a Gulp task, that find my Bower components** (let's say, in the default bower_components folder) **and concatene them to a single file** (i.e. js/libs.js) when I install a new component.

I tried to use [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) to achieve that, based on examples on the documentation :

```
gulp.task('jslibs', function() {
 return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()) // SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
});
```

So it's returning a syntax error when I run the task, I don't know why. I tried to pass some options, no success.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This may seem like a really stupid question but did you `require('main-bower-files)`? Is that module installed?

Comment: I did require('main-bower-files); I still don't know why this didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I didn't find a solution using main-bower-files**. So I tried another package : bower-files (`require('bower-files')();`).

And the working task look like this :

```
gulp.task('js-libs', function() {    
   gulp.src(lib.ext('js').files)
    .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

It just takes all the files set as dependencies in Bower and returns it. Then I concat / uglify and send it to my JS build folder (and then, the main JS task is watching for changes and add it to the main JS file, concat / uglify it and send it to the dist.

Answer (score 2):

First install your requirements:

```
npm install gulp gulp-concat main-bower-files -D
```

Then your `gulpfile.js` could look like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files'),

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.css' ,{debugging:true}))
        .pipe (concat ("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/js/vendor/"));
});
```

Then just do:

```
gulp bower
```

Comment: Why is the filter passed to mainBowerFiles '**/*.css', but this is concatinated in 'vendor.js'. Shouldn't that be 'vendor.css' ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This might be the issue. You do not have a bower.json file or you have an empty .bowerrc file